# Meaning of $P(d)$ in pLSA

Tags: topic-models, latent-semantic-analysis

Given the following [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis):
$$
{\displaystyle P(w,d)=P(d)\sum _{c}P(c|d)P(w|c)}
$$

How $P(d)$ is calculated? I suggest that's relative length of the document with respect to corpus:
$$
P(d)=\frac{\text{Number of words in document d}}{\text{Number of words in corpus}}
$$

Is that right?